# How do I know if the memory allocated for elasticsearch is enough or too much?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, memory

I came from this question [how to decide the memory requirement for my elasticsearch server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034752/how-to-decide-the-memory-requirement-for-my-elasticsearch-server).

People allocate memory with their own experience in this case, suppose if I allocate 64GB memory for Java heap, how do I know if it's enough or too much?